# Cleaner Way to Test for Types?

Tags: coffeescript

I defined a function that multiplies its argument by 3:

```
coffee> foo = (x) -> x * 3
[Function]
```

We can call it with an input of 1:

```
coffee> foo(1)
3
```

However, when I tried with a non-Number type:

```
coffee> foo("3")
9
```

This behavior appears wrong to me since a String cannot be multiplied by a Number.

To fix it, I'd add something like this:

```
foo = (x) ->
  if typeof x is 'number'
    x * 3
  else
    throw new Error("not a number:"  + x)
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CoffeeScript is, in the end, just JavaScript with a nicer syntax. So the string-interpreted-as-number behavior is expected and normal. You write:

> This behavior appears wrong to me since a String cannot be multiplied by a Number.

Yet, due to type coercion in JavaScript, a string *can* be multiplied by a number just fine. And, importantly, *the result is correct!*

Your options with regard to strict type-checking are:

1. Using `typeof` and throwing an exception (or handling it some other way), as you do now.
2. Doing nothing.

You're still writing JavaScript, so option #2 is a valid solution to most type concerns. For instance, most (all?) the functions in the `Math` object accept numerical strings just as well as numbers.

For other types, the GIGO principle usually applies: Garbage In, Garbage Out. I.e. if the user of your code passes something completely incompatible, like an object, they'll get `NaN` back. And that's their problem, really. Same as if you do `Math.floor({})` or something.

However, if type-checking is absolutely necessary, you can at least slim your code down a bit:

```
foo = (x) ->
  throw new TypeError unless typeof x is 'number'
  x * 3
```

Note that the code throws a `TypeError`, which is more appropriate for this situation, and that, since it throws, execution of the function is halted just as effectively as writing `return`. So there's no need for `if...else` branches.

You can generalize it a bit with a function, if you need to do this more often:

```
assertNumber = (value) ->
  unless typeof value is 'number'
    throw new TypeError("Expected a Number")
```

Or, better yet, check whether the value is *numeric*:

```
assertNumeric = (value) ->
  if isNaN Number(value)
    throw new TypeError("Expected a numeric value")
```

And use it like so:

```
foo = (x) ->
  assertNumeric x
  x * 3
```

Comment: This is a very good answer.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful, solid answer. However, I don't like this statement - `if the user of your code passes something completely incompatible, like an object, they'll get NaN back. And that's their problem, really`. I understand your `GIGO` point, but a well-built function shouldn't just blow up upon bad input, in my opinion. Although perhaps this state-of-mind is commonplace in JavaScript? I primarily work in the back-end (Java/Scala).

Comment: @KevinMeredith Well, that's sort of the point of GIGO: The function _doesn't_ blow up; it executes and returns. Throwing an exception would be more akin to "blowing up". Of course, you can catch exceptions, but if you fail to catch one, script execution is just halted. Meanwhile, checking for `NaN` is pretty simple and doesn't require a couple of lines of `try...catch` code. JavaScript does use exceptions from time to time, yes, but for the most part it's GIGO and loose typing. Again, look at something like `Math.floor`

Comment: thanks, Flambino. I didn't intend to say "state-of-mind" in a rude way. I had meant, "perhaps `GIGO` is standard in JavaScript libraries". But your follow-up response helped me out in your recommendation to throw an Exception or return NaN, thus avoiding the try/catch.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Oh, no offense taken (and thanks for the checkmark). JS libraries vary in how they handle bad input. Judging by how rarely I write `try...catch` statements, I'd say GIGO is somewhat more common than `throw` statements (or maybe I _should_ be writing `try...catch` more often, but it rarely seems necessary). Of course, if you're in a situation where it's impossible to even return garbage then by all means throw an exception.

Comment: Overall, using Scala's `Option` or Haskell's `Maybe`'s equivalent in JavaScript is better than returning garbage, `null`, or `undefined`. But, I'm not sure of such a data type in JS.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I must admit that I'm not intimately familiar with Scala or Haskell, but the closest I think you can get is to return `null` or `undefined`. The neat thing about CoffeeScript is that a) `undefined` is a proper keyword, unlike in JavaScript, and b) you can use the [existential operator (`?`)](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) to check whether something is _precisely_ `null`/`undefined` (but not some other other falsey value like `false`, zero or an empty string). Put all that together and I think you have pretty much the same functionality as `Option`/`Maybe`