# Implementing a Simple "MoneyAccount" in CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript

Please critique this CoffeeScript code. Is it idiomatic?

```
MoneyAccount = (balance = 0) ->
  obj = {
    withdraw: (x) ->
      if balance < x
        throw new Error("not enough funds in account")
      else
        balance -= x
        console.log "withdrew funds."
        x
    deposit: (x) ->
      if (typeof x isnt 'number' || x < 0)
        throw new Error("bad deposit amount " + x)
      else
        balance += x
    printBalance: ->
      console.log balance
  }
  obj
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This seems closely tied to [your other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/51619/14370). I posted [an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51631/14370) for that one, which I'll incorporate/reference here.*

Calling it `MoneyAccount` (in "UpperCamelCase") implies that it's a constructor. But it's not quite; it's just a function. But I assume that's done on purpose in order to have "private" variables (i.e. the closed-over `balance` argument) while still allowing one to invoke it with or without the `new` keyword.

Still, there are a couple of things you could do:

1. You're diligent in checking the input for `deposit` and `withdraw`... but not the initial balance. So `account = MoneyAccount("foo")` would spell trouble right away.
   But even if you check the type of the initial balance, it'd still allow someone input a negative initial balance. But the way `withdraw` works seems to imply that a negative balance is impossible.
   Incidentally, I could also say `account = MoneyAccount(1/0)` and have `Infinity` money! Sounds nice, but perhaps not what you want.
2. Similar to the above, there's nothing stopping you from withdrawing or depositing a negative or infinite amount.
3. As mentioned in the answer I linked to, you don't need `if...else` branches if you throw an an exception; the function will exit if it throws.
4. There's no way to just get the balance, which would seem problematic for an account. You can print it, sure, but you can't just *get* it. If you add a method to do that, you can skip the `console.log` stuff (which incidentally, you're only doing for `withdraw` but not for `deposit`). Logging stuff isn't really the responsibility of an account object anyway; leave that to external code.
5. `x` should probably be named `amount` instead, just to be descriptive.
6. You might want to throw a `RangeError` in `withdraw` to be a bit more precise.
7. Return values are a little haphazard. `deposit` returns the new balance while `withdraw` returns the amount withdrawn.
8. The `obj` var is unnecessary; you can just leave it out entirely. And you can even leave out the curly brackets (which I personally like to do in a case like this, but it's a matter to taste, really).

In the end, I get this:

```
MoneyAccount = (balance = 0) ->
  # Adapted from the linked answer
  assertValidAmount = (amount) ->
    number = Number amount
    if isNaN(number)
      throw new TypeError("Expected a numeric amount")
    if not isFinite(number) or number < 0
      throw new RangeError("Expected a positive, finite amount")

  assertValidAmount balance

  # everything below will be interpreted as an object
  # and returned, even without the curly braces

  balance: -> balance

  withdraw: (amount) ->
    assertValidAmount amount
    throw new RangeError("Insufficient funds") if amount > balance
    balance -= amount

  deposit: (amount) ->
    assertValidAmount amount
    balance += amount
```

That should be pretty safe.

Comment: I used the Function rather than `class` due to [CoffeeScript Ristretto](https://leanpub.com/coffeescript-ristretto)'s examples. With respect to `If it's not on purpose, and you'd be ok with having balance be publicly accessible`, how can that ever be acceptable? Thanks for your informative, detailed answer. I appreciate it.

Comment: @KevinMeredith I agree that a publicly accessible `balance` sounds like a bad idea - I just mentioned it because that'd be the consequence of using CoffeeScript's `class`. But in the end, JS doesn't have a built-in concept of private/public visibility or accessibility (e.g. you can redefine the functions and properties on existing prototypes), so it's often times easier to just leave things loose than erect and maintain a bunch of "artificial" barriers (similar to GIGO vs exceptions). Closed-over "private" vars are however simple to do, so that's encouraged!

Comment: If `class MoneyAccount` were used instead, then couldn't we always use a `normal variable` like so: `class Queue
  foo = "Hey there"
  constructor: ->
    ...`? When constructing a new object, `foo` wouldn't be accessible from without the `class MoneyAccount`, if I understand correctly. Example - https://gist.github.com/kman007us/18dd99f8962c88a874ae

Comment: @KevinMeredith Ah, of course, you are correct. My mistake; I was misremembering the syntax. I've edited the answer. Thanks for the correction